# How to extract zones that are contained in bigger zones from two different layers

Tags: qgis-2

I am newbie in QGIS. I have two layers lets say X1 and X2. The X1 is used as a background and consists of more zones than the X2 layer. 
[image]

For istance in the pic below zone 117 of the X1 layer, contains many smaller areas of the X2 layer. I would like to create a table with all the small areas contained in the zone 117.

How can I do it in QGIS?

Comment: I don't have QGIS in front of me and I have more experience in ESRI but you should search for 'Spatial Join'.  That should get you on the right path.

Comment: Thanks! This way I create a new layer. How can then I see the names of the smaller zones?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to the select the smaller features using a 'spatial query', then save those to a new dataset using 'save as'.

You'll first select the '117' feature from the X1 layer

Choose the menu option Vector > Spatial Query

Set the 'select source features from' and set that to X2

Then set the option for 'where the feature' to 'within' - but make sure that gets the features you're after, or you should choose 'contains'

Then ensure the box for '1 selected geometry' is checked.

Then when you've got the right features from X2 selected, right click the layer and choose 'save as', write out to a ESRI shapfile, and ensure the 'save only selected features' is checked, and you should be good.

Comment: @Marios great - if that worked for you, please mark it as your answer.... Thanks!